# Change EditText UI In Android

Tags: android

I want to change all EditText UI In android. For example I want to change On Focus, On Blur and ... style. How can I do it? Actually I read some snippet, but I don't understand what they do!

Comment: please add some details & ask your question properly..

Comment: For example, when the edit text is on focus, I want to have a black border and gray background ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- create selector for different state

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_pressed" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_selected" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_selected" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
</selector>
```

2- To apply the customize drawable xml use the android:backgroung attibute of the EditText

```
android:background="@drawable/yourXml"
```

http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget

Comment: if you an add style then see the link http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the looks of EditText when certain events like onFocus, onPressed too place, then you will need Selector.

**Selector** is a drawable and is implemented as xml file, the elements in selector files will refer to specific state. Each Element maps to a specific state.

To change the look and feel of UI components, you can use **background, src attributes,etc**.

and this link is just the one thats needed.

```
         http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
```